# Failed building wheel for spidev

Tags: python-3.x, macos-big-sur, spidev

Following the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/spidev/) I am installing spidev with

```
pip3 install spidev
```

in Python 3.7.3 on a MacOS 11.4 and getting the following error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting spidev
  Using cached spidev-3.5.tar.gz (10 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: spidev
  Building wheel for spidev (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/tf/vd1f171x1cxcgc2sq0ttn_v00000gn/T/pip-install-u033u0oe/spidev_96f8104add874aca92e572d21798ca0a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/tf/vd1f171x1cxcgc2sq0ttn_v00000gn/T/pip-install-u033u0oe/spidev_96f8104add874aca92e572d21798ca0a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/tf/vd1f171x1cxcgc2sq0ttn_v00000gn/T/pip-wheel-df05b117
       cwd: /private/var/folders/tf/vd1f171x1cxcgc2sq0ttn_v00000gn/T/pip-install-u033u0oe/spidev_96f8104add874aca92e572d21798ca0a/
  Complete output (12 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'spidev' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
  xcrun -sdk macosx clang -arch x86_64 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Headers -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c spidev_module.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/spidev_module.o
  spidev_module.c:33:10: fatal error: 'linux/spi/spidev.h' file not found
  #include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for spidev
  Running setup.py clean for spidev
Failed to build spidev
Installing collected packages: spidev
    Running setup.py install for spidev ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/tf/vd1f171x1cxcgc2sq0ttn_v00000gn/T/pip-install-u033u0oe/spidev_96f8104add874aca92e572d21798ca0a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/tf/vd1f171x1cxcgc2sq0ttn_v00000gn/T/pip-install-u033u0oe/spidev_96f8104add874aca92e572d21798ca0a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/tf/vd1f171x1cxcgc2sq0ttn_v00000gn/T/pip-record-ivqzy7c8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/wogsland/Library/Python/3.7/include/python3.7m/spidev
         cwd: /private/var/folders/tf/vd1f171x1cxcgc2sq0ttn_v00000gn/T/pip-install-u033u0oe/spidev_96f8104add874aca92e572d21798ca0a/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'spidev' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
    xcrun -sdk macosx clang -arch x86_64 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Headers -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c spidev_module.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/spidev_module.o
    spidev_module.c:33:10: fatal error: 'linux/spi/spidev.h' file not found
    #include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/tf/vd1f171x1cxcgc2sq0ttn_v00000gn/T/pip-install-u033u0oe/spidev_96f8104add874aca92e572d21798ca0a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/tf/vd1f171x1cxcgc2sq0ttn_v00000gn/T/pip-install-u033u0oe/spidev_96f8104add874aca92e572d21798ca0a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/tf/vd1f171x1cxcgc2sq0ttn_v00000gn/T/pip-record-ivqzy7c8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/wogsland/Library/Python/3.7/include/python3.7m/spidev Check the logs for full command output.
```

Are there dependencies external to Python which I need to install first?